# Blender 2.79 How to remove the clipping in Material Viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

How to remove the clipping in Material Viewport?
[image]

I've already set the clip view settings.
It works on solid viewport but not in material.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First - insert images directly into your question (external links are not allowed, they are not permanent), thank you. Second please share your simplified file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com , it can be only a Cube, just issue has to be still there. That is not a Clipping, Clipping erase also grid and that is still there .... so some hidden object or some global alpha in material?

Comment: I don't understang about global alpha.
But I provide the file,  maybe you could take a look? 

Thak you.

Comment: Sorry I cant confirm your issue, on my comp with blender 2.79 is viewport OK in all modes. But what is not correct is animation it self. Opening in 2.92 is animation OK. Hm ... but you probably use some add-on, that I don't have, and it is achieved in newer version by default ...

Comment: Mmm... Try to click the tranform modifier: Rotate. 
Usually, it happened after clicking it. 

I don't use any add on. Just blender as is.

Comment: Same ... all fine. Here is anim from 2.79 https://imgur.com/HHd1wPj and here from 2.92 https://imgur.com/Abmlm4Z

Comment: Weird.
Regarding the animation. 
I use 2.79 and the animation is ok. 
But don't worry about it. 
Though, I'm not sure why it's so. 

The only problem at my side is the clip. 
Have you tried to zoom to the amature?
Or did you test it from far away?

Comment: Yes, zoom, rotate view, change pose mode to enemy, rotate hands legs, zoom again back and forth ... I know you don't care about issue with anim on my side, but from this I can smell there is something different between our environments. There can be enabled some add-on that or something that let your anim works, but also it can cause your visibility issue as well. Try to File > Load factory settings and open your file again ...

Comment: Load factory settings.
Load file. 
Done. 
But still the same from my side. 
I use 2.79b
Windows 10.

Comment: Could it be the graphic card? 
I use Ryzen 5, I use the onboard VGA that comes along with ryzen 5. 
I play around with the Render > OpengGL animation, and the animation result is the same as the image you've given.

Comment: Sorry I cant help more. I'm Mac user. Issues with card usually let disappear something entirely not partially, also it has no influence on animated armature, but Im not so techy ...

Comment: Solved.
It turns out, the problem was related to VGA. 
All I do was to update the software AMD Radeon.

Thank you, discussing this problem with you has shed some lights. I have this problem for almost a year. And I've searched the internet to no avail.